# change url parameter using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this URL

> /home/tx_besijobs_pi1 **%5Bpointer%5D=1**
>   &tx_besijobs_pi1%5Bmode%5D=1&cHash=70b49e9ffb83c0fb8010a7220bf4d833

I need to change the *pointer value to '0'* on next tab click.

My jquery script is given below

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookies.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var pointer = getUrlVars()["pointer"];

  $(function()
    {
            var cookieName ="stickyTab";

            $( "div.tabbing" ).tabs( {  

                selected: ( $.cookies.get( cookieName ) || 0 ),
                select: function( e, ui )
                    {
                            var id =  $(location).attr("href");
                            $.cookies.set( cookieName, ui.index );
                    }
                } );
    } );


   function getUrlVars()
     {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");

        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split("=");

            if($.inArray(hash[0], vars)>-1)
            {
                vars[hash[0]]+=","+hash[1];
            }
            else
            {
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
        }

        return vars;
    }
```

Since the URL is of the format **tx_besijobs_pi1%5Bpointer%5D=1** .I am not getting pointer value. And I dont know how to set pointer value to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say if `tx_besijobs_pi1%5Bpointer%5D=1` is the string and you need to change the value from 1 to 0

```
var str = 'tx_besijobs_pi1%5Bpointer%5D=1';
str = str.replace("5Bpointer%5D=1", "5Bpointer%5D=0");
```

This is just an example, you can use this approach to update your string and then create URL out of this

Comment: var pntr = getUrlVars()["tx_besijobs_pi1[pointer]"];
                                      
and I am getting pntr value as 1,2,...                                
   id = id.replace("[pointer]=pntr", "[pointer]=0"); This is not working.But if I put   id.replace("[pointer]=2", "[pointer]=0")  , Its working correctly.